# Passing UITextField Value to Function Within View

Tags: ios, function, uitextfield, scope

I'm just beginning with XCode and coding for iOS, have the following problem. I want to add a function that sets `UITextField` values in the `ViewController` based around the value from a `UIStepper`. The code actually handles formatting three `UITextField`s, cut it to one to shorten the example.  This code works fine:

```
- (IBAction)Temp_Stepper_Changed:(UIStepper *)sender {
    integer_t stepperValue = (integer_t) sender.value;
    NSString *temp_format = [[NSString alloc]
                             initWithFormat: @"%%.%df",stepperValue];
    double fahrenheit = [_TempF_Text.text doubleValue];
    NSString *FresultString = [[NSString alloc]
                               initWithFormat: temp_format,fahrenheit];
    _TempF_Text.text = FresultString;
}
```

I have several places I want to do this, so want to create a function to call, and so I put this function into the view controller's .m file:

```
void Temp_Text_Update (double F_Temp){
    NSString *FresultString = [[NSString alloc]
                               initWithFormat: @"%.2f",F_Temp];
    _TempF_Text.text = FresultString;
}
```

The function won't compile, results in error:

```
use of undeclared identifier '_TempF_Text'
```

Without the line, it compiles fine, can call the function, pass values, etc. I had assumed (remember, beginning at this) as the `UIStepper` had `_TempF_Text` in it's scope, the function being in the same .m file would as well. Is there some magic happening behind the scenes that allows the `IBAction` type calls to access any value from the `ViewController` items, but my function is missing said magic?  I'll also need the `UIStepper` value to complete the function.  This was built using Storyboard, control-drag for outlets and actions, header file is:

```
@interface TemperatureViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TempF_Text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *Temp_Stepper;

- (IBAction)TempF_CnvButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Temp_Stepper_Changed:(UIStepper *)sender;
```

I've spent a few hours searching, including this site, found references from one `ViewController` to another and so forth, but doesn't really match; tried a few things anyway, but nothing worked (though some yielded extra errors). I suspect it is so obvious and simple as to not be asked, but I've run out of ideas and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the convention for objective-c names for methods and properties is to use camel case with the first letter being lowercase (uppercase for classes). So Temp_Stepper_Changed should be tempStepperChanged:. Your code will be easier for others to read if you go with the convention.

Comment: Is the error undeclared identifier '_Temp_Text', as you have in your question, or undeclared identifier '_TempF_Text'?

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, rdelmar; will find and follow conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the specific question, the correct syntax for the signature you're trying to write would look like this:

```
- (void)Temp_Text_Update:(double)F_Temp {
```

This says we have a method named Temp_Text_Update: that takes a double parameter called F_Temp and doesn't return anything.

A more general solution would be to use NSNumberFormatter to go between strings and doubles in a locale sensitive way, something like this:

```
// get a double from a string
- (double)doubleFromString:(NSString *)string {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:string];
    return [number doubleValue];
}

// get a string from a double: 
- (NSString *)stringFromDouble:(double)aDouble {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    return [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aDouble]];
}
```

Then your computing functions would look like this:

```
NSString *text = self.someControlView.text;
double aDouble = [self doubleFromString:text];

// do computation on aDouble, resulting in
double result = // whatever
[self setOutputTextWithResult:result];
```

Finally, your method (better named):

```
- (void) setOutputTextWithResult:(double)result {
    self.someControlView.text = [self stringFromDouble:result];
}
```

It's so short now, it almost doesn't need it's own method.

Comment: Changed the method format to "- (void) setTemperatureFields:(double)fahrenheitTemp {"

Comment: Based on above, changed the method format to **- (void) setTemperatureFields:(double)fahrenheitTemp {** and changed **_TempF_Text.text = FresultString;** to **self.TempF_Text.text=FresultString;**. Adding the **self.** wouldn't work the way the method was written on mine, though the method worked okay as far as calling it and executing other code - just wouldn't allow reference to UITextField or the UIStepper. Will play with the NSNumberFormatter; purpose of method is to format text fields to a number of decimals provided by the stepper value. Lots to learn, thanks for help!